# Употребление слова "специфический"

Tags: выбор-слов

1. Правильно ли употреблять прилагательное "специфический" по отношению к неодушевленному предмету: специфический характер человека, например?
2. Тот же вопрос о слове "специфичный".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1-2. А почему нет?
"Специфичный" и "специфический" - синонимы, со значением "характерный, отличительный, особый". Есть, пожалуй, некоторые особенности употребления, не очень существенные, вот здесь можно посмотреть обсуждение (без гарантии, что профессиональное).
https://otvet.mail.ru/question/166380930

***Но уж точно нет никаких ограничений на использование того и другого по принципу одушевленности объекта***. Даже непонятно, откуда такое предположение могло возникнуть. Наоборот, основное использование - как раз то, которое вы указали. Вот "специфичный/специфический человек" - это какое-то особое, именно что "специфичное", употребление, но и его ничто и никто не ограничивает.

Answer (score 1):

СПЕЦИФИКА,  Совокупность отличительных особенностей чего-л.

СПЕЦИФИЧЕСКИЙ, [от лат. specificus - преобразующий] 1. Свойственный только данному предмету, **лицу,** явлению и т.п.; характерный, отличительный. С. запах больницы. С-ие черты, особенности, признаки, приметы кого-, чего-л. 2. Спец. Имеющий особое строение, состав, свойство. С-ие белки.

СПЕЦИФИЧНЫЙ,  =Специфический

**Если сравнивать слова специфичный и специфический по значению** (с учетом суффиксов), то **специфичный** - это внутренне особенный, а **специфический** - имеющий набор  отличительных свойств. Однако в реальности они употребляются как синонимы, причем частотность у слова "специфический" выше.

Можно сказать: у него специфический вид, говор, взгляд, ум.

Вот интересный (скорее авторский) пример:

Человек требовался **специфический**, желательно со справкой из психдиспансера, чтобы легче было оправдываться. [Артем Тарасов. Миллионер (2004)]